# delete values in dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

Why this code is not going to the second "if part" but when I comment out the remove statements then it is going to the second "if part" 
i need to take out 'abc' and 'abcd' and 'defg' from d['a']
below is my code.

```
d={'a': ['abc','def','ghi','abcd','ghij'], 'b': [6, 7, 8]}
for i in d['a']:
    if i.startswith("a"):
        d['a'].remove(i)
        #print('1st print '+i)
    if i.startswith("d"):
        d['a'].remove(i)
        #print('2nd print '+i)
print(d)
```

Comment: You are removing an element ('abc', so that lets the 'def' part move to the first position. Then your loop iterates to the second position. Don't remove elements of a list in a loop iterating that list.

Comment: You can do that if you iterate on the `reversed()` list though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a good practice to remove element from a list while iterating over it. In your case you can use a simple list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
d={'a': ['abc','def','ghi','abcd','ghij'], 'b': [6, 7, 8]}
d["a"] = [i for i in d["a"] if not i.startswith(("a", "d"))]

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': ['ghi', 'ghij'], 'b': [6, 7, 8]}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but can you tell me what is wrong with this  below code as now i am storing the elements to one list and i am iterating over that and deleting from dictionary.                                                                                                                                d={'a': ['abc','def','ghi','abcd','ghij'], 'b': [6, 7, 8]}
a=d['a']
for i in a:
    if i.startswith("a"):
        d['a'].remove(i)
        #print('1st print '+i)
    if i.startswith("d"):
        d['a'].remove(i)
        #print('2nd print '+i)
print(d)

Comment: Please read the ans carefully...you cannot use remove correctly. while iterating the list.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you remove elements from the list while iterating over its `reversed()` version.

```
d={'a': ['abc','def','ghi','abcd','ghij'], 'b': [6, 7, 8]}
for i in reversed(d['a']):
    if i.startswith("a"):
        d['a'].remove(i)
        #print('1st print '+i)
    if i.startswith("d"):
        d['a'].remove(i)
        #print('2nd print '+i)
print(d)
```

Output:
`{'a': ['ghi', 'ghij'], 'b': [6, 7, 8]}`

This is because when you remove an element and iterate from the **start** of the list, the elements you haven't **checked yet** may change their position in the list. This doesn't happen when iterating in reverse order, from the **end**.